# Is it possible to inject a Saved session data from Baileys into a normal Whatsapp web client?

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I am writing a js programm unsing the npm package `@adiwajshing/baileys` and saved a whatsapp session in a folder.

Now I want to inject the session from my programm to the official whatsapp web client.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try Whatsapp-web.js
It has localauth.
I'm doing an aplication in it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).